# How pointer "gets informed" about which part of the pointed object can access?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

Basic [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9440ca7a8c43022a):

```
class Base
{
public:
    double mValue = 10.0;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    double mAdditionalValue = 20.0;
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    Base *rBase = &derived;
    std::cout << "value " << rBase->mValue << '\n';
    std::cout << "additionalValue " << rBase->mAdditionalValue << '\n';
}
```

Obviously I can't access to `mAdditionalValue` via `rBase` because the reference type (`Base`) its not `Derived`, and doesn't contain a member called `mAdditionalValue`. Nice! Smart mechanism! But how in fact that's implemented in C++?

I mean: `rBase` point anyway to an object of type `Derived`, and in the memory its stored that `mAdditionalValue` (I've created it). So it points to the whole object. It could "physically" access to that data.

Who "block/limit" the pointer scope accessibility? Its within the logic of pointer (so a software implementation) or is the compiler, in compiling phase, to catch this and block the operation? And how would do that? Checking memory addresses and limits them?

Comment: This all happens at compile time.

Comment: When you do `rBase->mAdditionalValue` the compiler looks up the name `mAdditionalValue` in the scope of `Base` (because `*rBase` has type `Base`) and finds nothing, giving a compilation error

Comment: The compiler knows what the type of `rBase` is, because it parses the source code, and then applies rules of the language in deciding what is allowed (e.g. accessing `mValue` member) and what is not (e.g. accessing the `mAdditionalValue` member).

Comment: How does it get informed? C++ is statically typed. What's the pointer type?

Answer (score 5):

I am going to tell you a [lie we tell children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children).  Like when we tell them why the sky is blue, or that the world is round.

So the compiler knows that given a pointer to `Base`, `mValue` is located at a fixed offset from the address of `Base` (in the above case, I'd bet 0).

So it translates `rBase->mValue` into "get the double at offset 0 from where rBase points".  It does this by looking at the static type of `*rBase` (at compile time), looking up what the offset of `mValue` is *in that type*, and rewriting your code to no longer know about `rBase`'s type, just a pointer and an offset.

All is well.

When you ask for `rBase->mAdditionalValue` it tries to lookup `mAdditionalValue`'s offset in the static type of `*rBase` at compile time and it isn't there.  So it generates an error.

You could imagine a language that would go a step further and say "well, `mAdditionalValue` is defined in a derived type!  Just use that offset!".

```
class Derived2: public Base
{
public:
  double bob=0;
  double mAdditionalValue = 20.0;
};
```

oh oh; now there are two derived types, and they disagree on what the offset of `mAdditionalValue` is with respect to a `Base` pointer to the object.  So now this non-C++ compiler has to determine the runtime type of `*rBase` to work out the offset, which in turn requires overhead.

There is a mechanism in C++ to do this for methods (virtual functions) not data, but even there you;d have to make the method virtual in Base (otherwise making efficient tables becomes insanity).  In theory C++ could have virtual data members.

So there isn't a zero cost way to solve what you seem to want in general.

---

For a different lie, what you ask for violates encapsulation.  You have no business asking for `mAdditionalValue` from a `Base*`.  Even if it was easy, C++ should say no.  The runtime behaviour if we are wrong about a pointer we blindly follow is bad.  It should be explicit or impossible.

---

The real answer is, because the standard says so.  You must put the name of a method or data field of `Base` to the right of `Base->`.  Anything else is an ill formed program.

---

Now you can make your code compile.

```
std::cout << "additionalValue " << static_cast<Derived*>(rBase)->mAdditionalValue << '\n';
```

here we tell it we know it is Derived and everything works with 0 runtime cost (if we are right) and undefined behaviour if we are wrong.

---

Here is a possible memory layout:

```
....
0x1110FFFF
0x11110000 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110001 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110002 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110003 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110004 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110005 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110006 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110007 DERIVED  BASE  mValue
0x11110008 DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x11110009 DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x1111000A DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x1111000B DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x1111000C DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x1111000D DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x1111000E DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x1111000F DERIVED  mAnotherValue
0x11110010 
...
```

A pointer at `0x11110000` could be pointing at `DERIVED`, `BASE` or `mValue`, or even just the byte at `0x11110000` -- they have in more than one sense the same address.  A given pointer, however, points at only one of these as determined by the *type* of the pointer.

A `Base*` pointer with value `0x11110000` is pointing at the `BASE` suboject of `DERIVED`.

Comment: Ok. But "actually" `rBase` points to the derived object, not a sort of "hybrid" derived with only base part visibility. Read this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/113-order-of-construction-of-derived-classes/ It seems there are "two part" object in the memory, which is not what happens I believe!

Comment: @markzzz - No, `rBase` points at a `Base`. Always. That `Base` may be in fact a sub-object of a `Derived`, but it's still a `Base`.

Comment: @markzzz you get a similar effect in a much simpler scenario. Consider `int a = 5; const int& b = a;` you arent allowed to mutate `a` through the reference `b`, even though the original `a` is not `const`.

Comment: Gee my children have never heard of this one before

Comment: @StoryTeller this is somethings I don't get :) I pass the address of `derived` to `rBase`. So its point to THAT derived object. Even if I can't access to some of its data, the object pointed (the address) point to a derived one. Or does object slicing/frankestobject to a new one?

Comment: It points to the same address: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64728632d7c805e4 So the pointed object should be derived. Not a "hybrid" one.

Comment: @markzzz You should read up on what types and statically typed means. Your question isn't what the address' value is, its about whether the compiler can understand what you wrote. Hint: it can't

Comment: @markzzz - You converted the address of a `Derived` to a pointer to `Base`. The conversion is implicit, and probably a no-op in this case, but it's a conversion nonetheless. You point to a `Base` object, nestled in another object.

Comment: @markzzz it points at the Base subobject, which is at offset 0 within the Derived object.  Also at offset 0 is the double mValue.  `Base* rBase=&derived;` takes the pointer to derived, finds the base subobject (offset 0 in this case), adjusts the pointer (adds 0), then stores it in `rBase`.  Do the same thing where the offset isn't 0 and the statement still works, such as `struct A{char a;}; struct B{char b;}; struct D:A,B{};` -- here, the offset of the `B` subobject is non-zero within `D`.  Yet `D d; B* pb = &d;` still works.

Comment: @Yakk of course. But if I take that pointer and I add "some offset" that would reach `mAdditionalValue`, that data exist! Compiler doesn't permit this, but what I'm trying to understand is that in memory there isn't a derived object AND a base object for `derived`. Its still the same object :)

Comment: @markzzz there is a derived object.  Part of that derived object is `mAdditionalData`, another part is a `Base` subobject.  Within that `Base` subobject there is a `mData`.  You can point to part of an object, even to the first part of an object, without pointing to the object.  Pointers are not just addresses (numbers), they also have types.

Comment: So, `rBase` point to where the Base object "start" within Derived object in memory. When compiler looks at the pointer, it know where to access (its address) and what can be access (its type). If it try to access to somethings its not declared on the "pointed type, it throw a compiler error. Am I correct?

Comment: @markzzz Yes.  That does however mix runtime and compile time behavior a bit, but it it close enough.  (In some senses the compiler doesn't know where pointers point, just their types, until runtime; but that is a lie, because optimizers often know)

Comment: @Yakk: well I'm talking about "virtual addresses". Than at runtime what happens its a "offset" from the real memory, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166696/discussion-between-markzzz-and-yakk).

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Yakk 's answer with what I believed you did not understand from your comment:

To represend base and derived in memory:

> [base]
>
> [-------derived]

Your pointer will have the adress of '[' the beginning of your object in memory.
If you look at derived, it's way bigger than base : it's because it contains base, in fact derived is

> [base-derived]

Now what happens when you do the following ?

```
Base *rBase = &derived;
```

Here your pointer points to a base

> [base]
>
> ^

Even if in memory it is in fact

> [base-derived]
>
> ^

To summarize, your pointer has the address of a base, even if this base is contained inside a derived. Since your pointer has the address of a base it can't access data of derived because at compile time it does not have knowledge of this.

At runtime, you could cast your pointer to a pointer to derive and you will have no issue.

Comment: Yes, as I thought the object in memory is `[base-derived]`. So, compiler is of type `Base`, and know that can access only the address 0 + sizeof(Base)?

Comment: @markzzz It's more like : the type is base so the compiler only know members whose name are declared in base. Using rBase->mAdditionalValue would be like rBase->foobar , both have unknown name